# Does the UB due to modifying a variable twice between sequence points carry over to "inner" scopes?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

The following has unspecified results because evaluation order is unspecified:

```
std::string f() {
   std::cout << "f()";
   return "";
}

std::string g() {
   std::cout << "g()";
   return "";
}

int main() {
   std::cout << f() << g();
}

// Output: "f()g()" or "g()f()".
```

To the best of my knowledge, though, it's not invoking undefined behaviour.

However, *modifying* a variable twice between sequence points is definitely UB, e.g.:

```
int main() {
   int x = 0;
   std::cout << x++ << x++;
}
```

Now, does that rule refer only to the current scope, or would the following also be UB?

```
int foo() {
   static int x = 0;
   x++;
   return x;
}

int main() {
   std::cout << foo() << foo();
}

// Output: "12" or "21", or is it undefined?
```

The reason I ask is that my GCC 4.7.0 20111217 doesn't warn on snippet 3, but (of course) will on snippet 2.

Comment: Er, ok, maybe snippet 1 is the same as snippet 3, because it modifies the stream. Let's just gloss over that..! :$

Comment: AFAIK the behavior would be unspecified and not undefined.

Comment: I'm not sure this example is what you want. These two `foo()` aren't being passed as parameters to the same function. You are calling two functions, like this `cout.operator<<( foo() ).operator<<( foo() )`. Would this not alter the answer? Surely the first return must be computed before the second function call and its order is well defined?

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: The first return must be computed before the second function call, yes, but the arguments may be evaluated in any order...

Comment: The unspecified order only applies to arguments of the same function call. You have two distinct function calls here: the arguments are not mixed.  That is, you actually have _four_ function calls, two to `foo` and two to `operator<<`. I think the calls to the `operator<<` are sequenced.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: function parameters are not the only things that have unspecified order. Evaluation order of sub-expressions is also mostly unspecified. So in `X.func(foo()).func(bar())`, the implementation can evaluate subexpression `bar()` first, then `foo()`, then `X.func(foo())`, then the final `func` call. So the output of Tomalak's code *can* be `"12"` or `"21"` according to whether `foo()` or `bar()` is evaluated first. It just happens that `bar` is `foo` in his example, of course. The calls to `operator<<` are sequenced as you say, but that doesn't determine the output.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y The calls to `operator<<` are sequenced, since the results of the first call serve as argument to the second call.  But this doesn't impose any constraints on the ordering of the calls to `foo`.

Comment: @James, if the calls to `operator<<` are well defined then I'd say the calls to `foo` must also be well defined.  Perhaps I'll ask another question, to be clearer.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: You might say that, but you'd be wrong.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal, I was just thinking out loud. I've read, and reread section 1.9. I'm not sure James answer is absolutely correct, but it isn't wrong either.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y The calls to `foo` are well defined.  The order in which they occur is unspecified, so the actual output is unspecified (but restricted to a very small finite set of possiblities).

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y What might not be absolutely correct in my response?  (Whether it's useful or not is another question.  In practice, unspecified behavior isn't really more useful than undefined behavior, at least if you want deterministic output from the program.)

Comment: @JamesKanze, perhaps the language between 03 and C++11 has changed.  Nothing in section 1.9 indicates distinct sequence points with custom types. The wording about the function only indicates sequenced before the function, the end part is left somewhat implicit. Of course nothing in the standard refers to a _sequence point_ at all anymore.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y The language has changed considerably; the concept of sequence points doesn't work in a multithreaded environment.  The intent is, however, that the meaning in a single threaded environment remain unchanged.  In both cases, the fact remains that the order in which the calls to `foo` occur is unspecified (but there is no undefined behavior as a result of the multiple calls).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both calling a function and returning from a function are sequence
points, so nothing you do in one function can conflict with what you do
in another (even if the order in which the functions are called is
unspecified).

Note that in this regard, user defined operator overloads are functions,
and introduce sequence points that wouldn't be present for built in
types.  So that something like `cout << i++ << i++` isn't undefined
behavior if `i` is a user defined type (e.g. an enum with a user defined 
`operator++`).  (The order is still unspecified, however, and just
because the behavior is defined doesn't mean that the code is readable
or recommendable.)

Comment: Can you check my comment on the main question? If calling a function is a sequence point, then the behaviour is completely specified here, since the first call to `operator<<` happens before the second call to `foo`.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y Why?  The only constraints on the order are `foo[1]` before `op<<[1]`, `foo[2]` before `op<<[2]` and `op<<[1]` before `op<<[2]`.  Any order which fulfills those constraints is legal, and something like `foo[2]`, `foo[1]`, `op<<[1]`, `op<<[2]` wouldn't surprise me at all.

Comment: If anyone is standards-diving for this, IIRC return from a function isn't explicitly a sequence point, but the end of a statement is, and every function ends with a statement. Usually a return statement, but if some `void` function contains only an empty statement it has no side-effects, so that's OK anyway.

Comment: Section 1.9 covers this topic, with _sequenced before_ defined at point 13.

Comment: From C++03 §1.9/17: "When calling a function (whether or not the 
function is inline), there is a sequence point after the evaluation of
all function arguments (if any) which takes place before execution of
any expressions or statements in the function body. There is also a
sequence point after the copying of a returned value and before the
execution of any expressions outside the function".

Comment: @SteveJessop C++03 explicitly mentions returns.  This may be because the return statement executes actions outside of the expression it contains (but I have my doubts about this, since those actions may be elided).  I'm less familiar with C++11; everything concerning sequence points has been rewritten to define what happens (or doesn't) in a multithreaded environment.

Answer (score 4):

ISO14882:2011(e) says in 1.9-15 :

When calling a function (whether or not the function is inline), every value computation and side effect associated with any argument expression, or with the postfix expression designating the called function, is sequenced before execution of every expression or statement in the body of the called function.

So the order of foo calls is still unspecified, but certainly not UB.

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant. `foo` does not take any arguments, so it doesn't really matter how it is sequenced relative to its arguments.

Comment: @Mankarse: the return of foo is the argument to op<< here, as such all calls to foo are sequenced before their op<< calls, so everything is reduced to the qeustion what happens when you call foo() two times.

Answer (score 2):

The order of evaluation of the two calls to `foo()` is unspecified. The first one called will return 1 and second will return 2, so the result will depend on the compiler's choice of evaluation order. However, since there are sequence points within `foo()`, I'd guess that it isn't UB — the side-effect of `x++` is guaranteed to be complete before the function returns.

Comment: Yes, I know that. That's not the question!

Comment: It didn't exist when I wrote my comment. :) (And, yes, I'd _just_ refreshed.)

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: I know. It's my fault — I didn't read the question carefully enough on the first pass.